# How to say GPS in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I ask the following question in Spanish?

> Can you please send me the GPS coordinates of the hotel?

The translation of GPS (Global Positioning System) is `Sistema de posicionamiento global`. Therefore, should I say `coordenadas SPG`? Or would most Spanish speakers still refer to it as `coordenadas GPS`?

Comment: The Spanish WIkipedia refers to it throughout as GPS not SPG https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mdewey commented, in Spain - I don't know which Spanish variant are you asking for -, we use the English acronym GPS but pronouncing each letter in Spanish: Ge Pe Ese.

In any case in your sentence, we would omit the GPS part, you can ask just for the **coordinates**. If you're using an app like Whatsapp or Telegram, as others have answered you can ask for **ubicación** or **localización**.

> ¿Puede mandarme la **localización** del hotel?

Answer (score 1):

The usual and generic term used in Spanish for a position request for devices is *localización*:

> ¿Puede usted enviarme la *localización* del hotel al móvil?

Comment: Just to be clear: that will result in the person understanding that they should send the GPS coordinates, as opposed to two cross streets?

Answer (score 1):

No deberías decirlo así. Tanto *coordenada GPS* como *coordenada SPG* suenan muy cursi, ya sea en lenguaje formal o informal. Considero que **ubicación** es la mejor traducción del término que estás buscando y las formas en las que yo lo preguntaría serían:

> ¿Me podés/puedes mandar la ubicación del hotel, por favor? (informal)

> ¿Podrías mandarme la ubicación del hotel, por favor? (menos informal)

> ¿Podría enviarme la ubicación del hotel, por favor? (formal)